# Visual Studio 2013: DataGridView query for words starting with

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I've written an app which is working with a SQL Server database(DataGridView with DataSource) and I was wondering how I could make a search (by id/name/etc). I've created it with a direct query on the DataGridView, something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE USER LIKE @USER + '%' (+'%' being added automatically).
```

Everything works well, but just with full word search, as an example: if I want to search the name John, I have to write John into the search box to give me the results. As "J" or "Jo" doesn't show me nothing. How can I modify the query to show me all the results starting with the string in the search box?

Thanks a lot in advance. Hope it isn't a stupid question, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Have a look at this  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like

Comment: Looks like that query should work for what you are describing. Have you tried running sql profiler to see exactly what you are sending to sql server?

Comment: IF you are using a DataGridView with a DataSource - no idea because there is so little details - you could use a RowFilter and not query the DB for such things

Comment: What does '@USER' equal?

Comment: @jdweng, '@USER' equal the values of users in the DataGridView.

Comment: @Bhanupratap, I know to use SQL, but I need to collect a variable from a search box and to compare it with the data in the database. It works, but just as a plain, I need also words which will start with the word written in the search box.

Comment: @SeanLange, I'm sending to sql server the text, but it compares it. I mean if I write John, it will return all the users with the name John, but it is not returning Johnny, for example.

Comment: @Plutonix, yes, I'm using DataGridView with a DataSource. Sorry, I've forgot to add this. I will do it right now.

Comment: If your query is as you say it is and the value is John it would return Johnny also. That is what like does in that kind of query. There is obviously something else going on here. You need to provide some actual details.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is by just querying all the data from the database once, and filtering the data in the datagridview, otherwise this will cost you a query each time you filter.

So keep it like:

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE

and use this as followed:

```
(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);
```

Goodluck!